# Idiom for analysing something from a strange perspective

Tags: idiom-requests

What is an idiom for analysing, describing, or understanding something from an unusual point of view? A sentence using it might be:

> If you _______, it is quite similar to a burrito.

With the similarity with burritos being rather surprising from the most usual perspective. I'm quite sure there was an idiom with the form "look at it ____", but I'm drawing a blank on what it was.

*Clarification*: The answers so far might work, but some of them are more neutral than what I'm thinking of. I want to suggest oddity.

Comment: If you can grokamole, it's quite similar to a burrito.

Comment: If you let your imagination take flan, it's quite similar to a burrito.

Comment: Is it chili in here, or is it quite similar to a burrito?

Comment: If you consider arroz by any other name, it's quite similar to a burrito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at it cockeyed....

Comment: Matches what I intended in both tone and meaning. Also, searching for it led me to "if you squint", which is the common expression I was trying to recall.

Answer (score 5):

Look at it *from a different angle*?

Or what about ***if you think outside the box***?

Comment: Perhaps, but I wonder if there is something that also suggests oddity.

Comment: @duplode - see my edit.

Comment: "Thinking outside the box" puts the focus on the person doing the thinking. Also, it is a little too positive - it might imply the alternative perspective is ultimately the better one.

Comment: Also, *look at it from the outside*.

Comment: If you think outside the tortilla, it's quite similar to a tostada.

Answer (score 4):

*If you **think laterally**, it is quite similar to a burrito*.

Comment: It kind of fits. Like "think outside the box", though, it seems to be more about the thinker than about the thought.

Comment: Marty, it's perfect! You're just not thinking 4th dimensionally!

Comment: @duplode The term, and the concept was coined by management scientist [Edward de Bono](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=50&site=&source=hp&q=edward+de+bono&oq=edward+de+bono&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.1285.5293.0.5732.15.13.0.2.2.0.141.1625.0j13.13.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..1.14.1533.0.zyZAItI7Xsg)

Answer (score 2):

If you approach it tangentially, ...

Comment: Closest so far. A nitpick is that ideally I would have something less formal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something less formal than tangential, how about "If you approach it slaunchwise....."  I can't find a good reference for it, but it has been in use at MIT for decades, meaning tilted in a strange way.

Comment: If you ignore the issue of how uncommon this word seems to be, it fits perfectly! [Slaunchways (link to thesaurus.com)](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/slaunchways) seems to be slightly more common as far as Google can tell.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness: ***If you squint hard enough*** is the expression I couldn't recall at first.

Comment: I do not think this is complete actually "If you squint at it hard enough, it kinda looks like a [common noun]." It implies that the vague similarity requires some strenuous examination to ascertain. You could use "look" or "kind of"  for style instead of squint or kinda or preface it with "I think" to make it strictly a matter of opinion but other variations seem unusual to me...

Comment: @Tonepoet That does seem to be the case. I'm editing the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Thinking **off-the-wall*** might suggest the oddity you want.

> If you **think off-the-wall**, it is quite similar to a burrito.

---

> *off-the-wall:* strange, often in a funny or interesting way [[*MacMillan*]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/off-the-wall)

Answer (score 0):

In the specific context of debate, *playing the devil's advocate* is the act of arguing from a perspective you don't personally align with, and is especially challenging when you personally disagree with that perspective (hence mention of "the devil"). It's actually often necessary in order to provide a substantial proponent for an unpopular point of view - otherwise, a debate against that point of view turns into a group ranting session.

It provides many benefits, including broadening your own understanding of the subject being debated by forcing you to look at it from a completely different perspective. More than once, this has led me to identify my own falsely-founded preconceptions and completely change my thoughts on several subjects.